# how to fair use another company's logo in personal blogs for review or tutorial purpose?

Tags: california, trademark, fair-use, online

Here is my initial question about adding creator information on some "artwork" that also contains other companies' logos.
[How to properly add creator information when the art work is done with other companies' logo?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84719/how-to-properly-add-creator-information-when-the-art-work-is-done-with-other-com)

Short summary:

> How can we properly add creator information when the artwork is done
> with other companies' logos? We just treat all those pictures which
> have other companies' logos and text as creative "artwork" (maybe a
> better word)?

[image]

Qne answer talks about **fair use**, How can we add the copyright information about this picture if we use it on my blogs/tutorials?

I would like to add following information into this picture,

> Creater: mysite.com
> logo copyright: google.com

using the **fair use** method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fair use does not apply to Trademark

Fair Use is only available for copyright material. Trademarks are solely for determining the source of goods or services and not subject to Fair Use.

### Trademark allows Nominative Use

Nominative use is naming the mark. It does **not** allow to use the mark itself.

- A flashlight for a Gameboy may say "For GameBoy(TM)", akin to the NAKI Action Light:
  [image: Box of a NAKI Action Light]
- A replacement oil filter may say "Fitting for Nissan Almera Tino (v10) 2000-2006 115 PS Diesel", or rather, they usually specify the exact OEM numbers and car models, like in the following excerpt:
  [image: Nissan OEM numbers for some Oilfilter]
- NEITHER may use the Nintendo, Gameboy, Nissan or Almera picture marks for the advertising. Do note, that NAKI didn't cover up the marks on their model Game Boy, which might or might not be a problem.

Comment: I am not able to follow the second and thrid example of Trademark allows, What do you mean by "A replacement oil filter may say "Fitting for Nissan Almera 2002 1 liter engine"" Please explain a bit. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user95432 there.

Comment: Thank you for the picture and the red  part to point out, so we use google trademark, it would be google(TM). 
But for the "say "Fitting for Nissan Almera Tino (v10) 2000-2006 115 PS Diesel", " part, why don't we also include TM after Nissan?

Comment: @user95432 Please consult your lawyer if you need the TM or not for you usecase. You can't use the logo of Google **at all**, that is the gist.